# htaccess for rewrite URL is not working for my website

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have dynamic URL website (irasol.com) while i navigate to menu the url shows like

http://irasol.com/index.php?id=1

I want url like this

```
domainname/home
domainname/aboutus
domainname/contactus
domainname/apply
```

home, aboutus, contactus, apply are menu name it is already in database.

my htaccess file is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.php$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Other than htaccess, could the PHP framework you are using being involved in how the URLs are named?  Some frameworks (e.g. Symfony) let you change the names and routes as you want to.

Comment: Thanks jim, i am not using any php framework. just i used simple php with database.

Comment: Can any body help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [B,L]
```

**Explanation**

- The first three conditions make sure that `domainname/aboutus` is not a real file, so that we don't rewrite files that already exist.
- `Options -Multiviews` removes a number of potential problems

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, get rid of the .php in your pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

You are not matching .php extensions in the request. You are only routing matches to a query string on a real .php extension

As for a better solution:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: One potential edit: I would not use `[^/]*` as it will redirect the root of the site to `index.php/id=`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. above given code is not working same result only. chk http://irasol.com